# Adding a Leaflet map based on php in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, leaflet

I use a php-script [within a plugin](https://de.wordpress.org/plugins/insert-php-code-snippet/) on a Wordpress-site to geocode an user-supplied address. After this I would like to visualize the point on a leaflet map. In order to do so I wanted to use the built-in functions [from the leaflet-map](https://de.wordpress.org/plugins/leaflet-map/) plugin. I tracked down the class for this in the `class.map-shortcode.php`[-file](https://github.com/bozdoz/wp-plugin-leaflet-map/blob/master/shortcodes/class.map-shortcode.php): `Leaflet_Map_Shortcode`. This class provideds the function `shortcode`. [This is also added to the shortcode](https://github.com/bozdoz/wp-plugin-leaflet-map/blob/master/class.leaflet-map.php) in Wordpress (Lines 135 onwards):

```
        'leaflet-map' => array(
        'file' => 'class.map-shortcode.php',
        'class' => 'Leaflet_Map_Shortcode');
                foreach ($this->_shortcodes as $shortcode => $details) {
        include_once $shortcode_dir . $details['file'];
        add_shortcode($shortcode, array($details['class'], 'shortcode'));
```

My Intention was using this in a straightforward way:

```
<?php
 ... some code for geocoding...
 $coords = array("lng" => 11, "lat" =>43 );

 $myMap= new Leaflet_Map_Shortcode;
 $myMap->shortcode($coords);
 ?>
```

But nothing happens (i.e. nothing is displayed). So this leads me to several questions:

- Why does this not work?
- What's the best way of debugging this code?
- Is there a better solution to my problem?

Comment: Shortcodes don't output by default. You need something to parse them. Where are you trying to output the shortcode? If you `var_dump( $myMap->shortcode($coords) )` what do you get?

Comment: thanks for the hint id did the trick (see answers).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it is very easy due to a hint in the comments:

```
$mapPrint = $myMap->shortcode($coords);
echo($mapPrint);
```